# how to switch jasper reports from xalan to saxon?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, saxon, xalan

We use jasperreports 4.1.1 in our project and it works fine but recently we've decided to switch to xslt 2.0 and the first thing i did - i changed xalan (which doesn't have xslt 2.0 implementation) to saxon. But the first report i run threw me NoClassDefFoundError:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xpath/CachedXPathAPI
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.XalanXPathExecuter.<init>(XalanXPathExecuter.java:45)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.XalanXPathExecuterFactory.getXPathExecuter(XalanXPathExecuterFactory.java:39)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.JRXPathExecuterUtils.getXPathExecuter(JRXPathExecuterUtils.java:85)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource.<init>(JRXmlDataSource.java:172)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRXPathQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRXPathQueryExecuter.java:91)
```

We don't have any explicit binding to xalan, but jaspereports has this property:

```
# Apache Xalan XPath executers are used by default
net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.executer.factory=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.XalanXPathExecuterFactory
```

I suppose that this property cause jasper to use xalan but i don't understand with what i can change it: i looked at the package **net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml** and i didn't found anything related to saxon. Does jasper work with xalan xslt processor only? If not then how to change it?

Answer (score 1):

Jasper is very configurable. I believe you can simply write your own XPathExecutionFactory and plug it into Jasper by using the appropriate environment varialbles. I personally would just deploy xalan und saxon in parallel, if I needed saxon for something else.